# If I connect a switch to the port of another switch, will it cause the forwarding table of the upper switch to be constantly updated?

Tags: switch, ethernet

If not, how will it determine which subnet to send the packets?

I mean the port forwarding table , instead of the arp routing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches do not have forwarding tables, nor do switches have any concept of subnets. Switches also do not have ARP tables.

You seem to be confusing routers with switches. Switches operate at layer-2, and routers at layer-3. A subnet is a layer-3 construct, and ARP resolves a layer-3 address into a layer-2 address. Switches do not remove the layer-2 frame, the way routers do, to even see the layer-3 packet addresses.

A switch builds and updates its MAC address table each time a frame enters an interface. A MAC address table is per switch. It makes no sense for one switch to update another switch's MAC address table.

A switch uses the MAC address table to figure out to which switch interface to send a frame. If the frame's MAC address is not in the switch MAC address table, the frame will be flooded to all the switch interfaces other than the one where it entered the switch.

Comment: *switches being "classic" switches that only perform bridging / L2 forwarding. Most modern switches (can) perfom layer 3 functions and maintain an ARP Table

Answer (score 0):

you will need to elaborate more exxactly what you want. I don't think you understand the difference between:

"port forwarding table": A router/fw can maintain something like this. It would forward packets incoming on port IPA/PortX to port IPB/PortY.

Forwarding Table: As Ron put it, see below. Just MAC Address mapping

ARP Table: Maps IP to MAC Address so that a switch know if something with destination IP A comes in it maps it to MAC Address B, which it then checks in it's mac address table/forwarding table and forwards it out the mapped interface.

The upper switch will learn the MAC Address of the connected switch, and that will be in the Forwardin/MAC Address Table.